# Can't access parallel Linux setup/environment

Tags: linux, permissions, amazon-ec2

I installed a new EC2 instance (Ubuntu 18), followed [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console) instructions for connecting via Putty, updated NodeJS and installed pm2 ([these](https://medium.com/@sgobinda007/setting-up-react-redux-application-for-production-and-hosting-in-aws-ec2-8bbb8bf3c643) instructions).

Everything worked well. I even set up a pm2 process to run my React app. Then I closed Putty.

Here's the problem: when I SSH back in (same way as before), it looks like my environment *rolled back*. NodeJS is the old version again and the pm2 command isn't recognized.

Running htop, I see my pm2 process is still running and can confirm that my React app still works. It seems like that all exists in some separate instance or session.

Any ideas or tips on how I can get back to my "other" instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 4.2 of the NodeJS instructions you followed, you setup NVM (Node Version Manager) which means you can manage multiple versions of NodeJS using the command `nvm`.

In the script that step had you run, there was a command for `nvm use 8.9.0` where that sets your current environment to use that specific version of NodeJS. Replace `8.9.0` with whichever version of NodeJS you are attempting to use that is available to `nvm`.

Once you issue that command after logging in, you should see the previous `nvm` environment you created.